# How do I change the value of input elements with a date ? val()/attr()/change() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date selection element

```
 @Html.RadioButton("radioTimeFilter", "range", false) Date Range
 <span id="dateRangeControls" style="display:none;">
      <input id="txtDateOneFilter" type="text" style="width: 70px;" value="test" @*placeholder="Start Date"*@ />&nbsp;to&nbsp;
      <input id="txtDateTwoFilter" type="text" style="width: 70px;" value="test" @*placeholder="End Date"*@ />
 </span>
```

and on document ready i'm trying to set these values being passed from another page

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#timeFilter").val("@ViewBag.timeFilter").change();
        console.log("@ViewBag.dateStart");
        console.log("@ViewBag.dateEnd");
        // below fails
        $("#txtDateOneFilter").attr("value", '@ViewBag.dateStart');
        $("#txtDateTwoFilter").attr("value", '@ViewBag.dateEnd');
        //
        $("#ddlDistrictFilter").val("@ViewBag.districtId").change();
    });
```

i've tried .val() and using .change() and a bunch of other things. Nothing seems to work. How can I change these values after the page loads

Comment: Are you sure the `id="timeFilter"` ?

Comment: it's the txtDateOneFilter and txtDateTwoFilter input fields i'm trying to change

Comment: Ok I'm confused.  You said you tried `val()` and `change()` which there are only two lines in your snippet that appear in that form.  Also, when changing the value you shouldn't use `attr()`.  Use `val(newValue)` as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ptckvo

Copy the code and modify the dateOne and dateTwo values with the ViewBag (keep the quote marks inside the val):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtDateOneFilter").val('@ViewBag.dateStart');
  $("#txtDateTwoFilter").val('@ViewBag.dateEnd');
});
```

If it doesn't work, maybe the problem is in the ViewBag values.